# Attempted to insert a null list

Tags: apex, soql

I'm having this problem. Every time I try to insert inputFields values to DB via Save button I either have this error

> Attempted to upsert a null list
>   Error is in expression '{!Save}' in component  in page neworderpage: Class.NewOrderController.Save: line 23, column 1

OR

when I instantiate the List object in Save method, it is not inserted into DB.

VF Page (please ignore missing beginning and end):

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:dataList value="{!Opportunities}" var="o" style="list-style-type: none">
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Products (Assets)">
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.Asset__r.Product2Id}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.Asset__r.Quantity}" /> 
                <apex:outputField value="{!o.Order__r.Asset__r.Price}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Order details">
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.Payment__c}" />  
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.Delivery__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.EffectiveDate}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Contact Info">
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.Contact__r.OwnerId}" />     
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.Contact__r.Email}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.Contact__r.MobilePhone}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.Contact__r.AssistantName}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Order__r.Contact__r.AssistantPhone}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Billing Address">
                <apex:inputText value="{!o.Order__r.BillingStreet}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!o.Order__r.BillingCity}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!o.Order__r.BillingPostalCode}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!o.Order__r.BillingCountry}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Shipping Address">
                <apex:inputText value="{!o.Order__r.ShippingStreet}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!o.Order__r.ShippingCity}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!o.Order__r.ShippingPostalCode}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!o.Order__r.ShippingCountry}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" title="Save" value="Save order" />
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:dataList>
</apex:form>
```

And my controller:

```
    public class NewOrderController {

    public List<Opportunity> oppList;


    public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
        List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();

        oppList = [SELECT *some query entries*
                   FROM Opportunity
                   WHERE Order__c != null];
        return oppList;
    }

    public PageReference Save(){

        upsert oppList; 

        return new PageReference('/apex/MyOrders');
    } 
}
```

What am I missing? Dev console does not throw any error.

Thank you in advance for help. I am kinda new to apex/soql/visualforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a [name shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) problem here.

You have `oppList` defined as a member variable as well as locally in the method `getOpportunities()`. So when you are accessing the list on the VF, you are not really populating the member variable. The member variable always remains `null` and thus you are getting the error in `Save()`.

Just remove the declaration `List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();`  from your `getOpportunities()` and use this instantiation at class level while declaring the variable and that should work.

Comment: Thank you. It helped a bit but it threw another error:

Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0061t000004qNM4AAM; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id] Error is in expression '{!Save}' in component in page neworderpage: Class.NewOrderController.Save: line 23, column 1

Any ideas? I have no clue. Partially.

Comment: Seems you are only updating the records, if that's the case then use `update` instead of `upsert`. For how upsert works, take a look at [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_section.htm) for details. If you have follow up questions on `upsert`, then that will categorize as a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) based on the format of SFSE.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to resolve it somehow. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a "[shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)" variable, so the class-level variable remains null. You need to remove the data declaration from the method:

```
public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
    // Uses the class-level variable
    oppList = [SELECT *some query entries*
               FROM Opportunity
               WHERE Order__c != null];
    return oppList;
}
```